# Синтаксис Heredoc странно работает

Tags: php

Почему выводит ошибку Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end?

```
<?php
$x=10;

echo <<<МЕТКА
$x
МЕТКА;
?>

<?php
$x=10;

echo <<<МЕТКА
$x
МЕТКА;   
?>
```

Но если скопировать весь php код выше и заменить его на код ниже, то ошибка пропадает, почему? визуально ничего не меняется.

И ещё я не понимаю, где тут-то ошибка?

```
<?php

echo <<<RRR
fff
RRR; 

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Во втором случае у вас после метки есть пробел, что запрещено правилами HEREDOC! Так же не нужно ; ставить после метки

```
<?php
$x=10;

echo <<<МЕТКА
$x
МЕТКА
?>

<?php
$x=10;

echo <<<МЕТКА
$x
МЕТКА
?>
```

Comment: А вообще рекомендую почитать php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc. А также задуматься о целесообразности применения именно HEREDOC. Как правило, используют 'текст' или "текст и /"экранируемые/" символы и {$перемен}ные"

Comment: если не секрет то в каком редакторе пишете код?

Comment: пишу в notepad++

Comment: @DivMan, попробуйте phpstorm, он дает пробную бесплатную версию на 1 месяц, а потом его можно просто переустановить. В любом случае, если вы планируете профессионально разрабатывать вам нужно будет использовать IDE. А огромным плюсом данной является проверка не только синтаксиса, но и использования переменных и т.п. Экономит огромное количество времени на отладку детских ошибок. скачать http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/